# A way to launch address book and select email recipients

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, addressbook

My requirement is,

From my Win Forms application, I want to launch outlook address book (and/or global address list - exchange server), 
Choose recipients and then populate a textbox with all the email addresses (or) distribution list.

Any clues? I searched several forums, but no one addresses this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article is a couple of years old but it may help you: http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3701241/Interacting-with-Outlook-from-a-WinForms-Application.htm

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the link. This is a great example. However, I am able to access the "Contacts" but not "Address Book".

Answer (score 0):

Look at the SelectNamesDialog object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176400(v=office.12).aspx